# What columns can be used in OUTPUT INTO clause?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to build a mapping table to associate the IDs of new rows in a table with those that they're copied from. The OUTPUT INTO clause seems perfect for that, but it doesn't seem to behave according to the documentation.

My code:

```
DECLARE @Missing TABLE (SrcContentID INT PRIMARY KEY )
INSERT INTO @Missing 
    ( SrcContentID ) 
SELECT cshadow.ContentID
    FROM Private.Content AS cshadow
    LEFT JOIN Private.Content AS cglobal ON cshadow.Tag = cglobal.Tag
    WHERE cglobal.ContentID IS NULL 

PRINT 'Adding new content headers'
DECLARE @Inserted TABLE (SrcContentID INT PRIMARY KEY, TgtContentID INT )
INSERT INTO Private.Content 
    ( Tag, Description, ContentDate, DateActivate, DateDeactivate, SortOrder, CreatedOn, IsDeleted, ContentClassCode, ContentGroupID, OrgUnitID ) 
    OUTPUT cglobal.ContentID, INSERTED.ContentID INTO @Inserted (SrcContentID, TgtContentID)
SELECT Tag, Description, ContentDate, DateActivate, DateDeactivate, SortOrder, CreatedOn, IsDeleted, ContentClassCode, ContentGroupID, NULL 
    FROM Private.Content AS cglobal
    INNER JOIN @Missing AS m ON cglobal.ContentID = m.SrcContentID
```

Results in the error message:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 34
Invalid column name 'SrcContentID'.
```

(line 34 being the one with the OUTPUT INTO)

Experimentation suggests that only rows that are actually present in the target of the INSERT can be selected in the OUTPUT INTO. But this contradicts the docs in the books online. The article on **OUTPUT Clause** has example E that describes a similar usage:

> The OUTPUT INTO clause returns values
>   from the table being updated
>   (WorkOrder) and also from the Product
>   table. The Product table is used in
>   the FROM clause to specify the rows to
>   update.

Has anyone worked with this feature?

(In the meantime I've rewritten my code to do the job using a cursor loop, but that's ugly and I'm still curious)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've verified that the problem is that you can only use `INSERTED` columns.  The documentation seems to indicate that you can use `from_table_name`, but I can't seem to get it to work (The multi-part identifier "m.ContentID" could not be bound.):

```
TRUNCATE TABLE main

SELECT *
FROM incoming

SELECT *
FROM main

DECLARE @Missing TABLE (ContentID INT PRIMARY KEY)
INSERT INTO @Missing(ContentID) 
SELECT incoming.ContentID
FROM incoming
LEFT JOIN main
    ON main.ContentID = incoming.ContentID
WHERE main.ContentID IS NULL

SELECT *
FROM @Missing

DECLARE @Inserted TABLE (ContentID INT PRIMARY KEY, [Content] varchar(50))
INSERT INTO main(ContentID, [Content]) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.ContentID /* incoming doesn't work, m doesn't work */, INSERTED.[Content] INTO @Inserted (ContentID, [Content])
SELECT incoming.ContentID, incoming.[Content] 
FROM incoming
INNER JOIN @Missing AS m
    ON m.ContentID = incoming.ContentID

SELECT *
FROM @Inserted

SELECT *
FROM incoming

SELECT *
FROM main
```

Apparently the `from_table_name` prefix is only allowed on `DELETE` or `UPDATE` (or `MERGE` in 2008) - I'm not sure why:

- `from_table_name`

Is a column prefix that specifies a table included in the `FROM` clause of a `DELETE` or `UPDATE` statement that is used to specify the rows to update or delete.

If the table being modified is also specified in the `FROM` clause, any reference to columns in that table must be qualified with the `INSERTED` or `DELETED` prefix.

Answer (score 21):

You can do this with a MERGE in Sql Server 2008. Example code below:

```
--drop table A
create table A (a int primary key identity(1, 1))
insert into A default values
insert into A default values

delete from A where a>=3

-- insert two values into A and get the new primary keys
MERGE a USING (SELECT a FROM A) AS B(a)
ON (1 = 0) -- ignore the values, NOT MATCHED will always be true
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT DEFAULT VALUES -- always insert here for this example
OUTPUT $action, inserted.*, deleted.*, B.a; -- show the new primary key and source data
```

Result is

```
INSERT, 3, NULL, 1
INSERT, 4, NULL, 2
```

i.e. for each row the new primary key (3, 4) and the old one (1, 2). Creating a table called e.g. #OUTPUT and adding " INTO #OUTPUT;" at the end of the OUTPUT clause would save the records.

Comment: MERGE statement is my new best friend :)

Comment: Good explanation and example here: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2010/01/06/merge-and-output-the-swiss-army-knife-of-t-sql.aspx

Comment: Just leaving this here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Answer (score 6):

I'm running into EXACTLY the same problem as you are, I feel your pain...
As far as I've been able to find out there's no way to use the from_table_name prefix with an INSERT statement.
I'm sure there's a viable technical reason for this, and I'd love to know exactly what it is.

Ok, found it, here's a forum post on why it doesn't work:
[MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/c1fe0b9c-9305-4cb0-9237-9374ff4fc03e/)

Comment: And it provides the clue to the solution. MERGE statement! Then @Simon managed to provide syntax. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution to this problem, it sadly involves a temporary table, but at least it'll prevent the creation of a dreaded cursor :)
What you need to do is add an extra column to the table you're duplicating records from and give it a 'uniqueidentifer' type.

then declare a temporary table:

```
DECLARE @tmptable TABLE (uniqueid uniqueidentifier, original_id int, new_id int)
```

insert the the data into your temp table like this:

```
insert into @tmptable
(uniqueid,original_id,new_id)
select NewId(),id,0 from OriginalTable
```

the go ahead and do the real insert into the original table:

```
insert into OriginalTable
(uniqueid)
select uniqueid from @tmptable
```

Now to add the newly created identity values to your temp table:

```
update @tmptable
set new_id = o.id
from OriginalTable o inner join @tmptable tmp on tmp.uniqueid = o.uniqueid
```

Now you have a lookup table that holds the new id and original id in one record, for your using pleasure :)

I hope this helps somebody...

Comment: Thanks, but this is only a viable solution if the key that I need to track is a uniqueidentifier. The whole problem I'm trying to solve is to track the IDENTITY value that's being allocated to a new row.

Answer (score 0):

(MS) If the table being modified is also specified in the FROM clause, any reference to columns in that table must be qualified with the INSERTED or DELETED prefix.

In your example, you can't use cglobal table in the OUTPUT unless it's INSERTED.column_name or DELETED.column_name:

```
INSERT INTO Private.Content 
    (Tag) 
    OUTPUT cglobal.ContentID, INSERTED.ContentID 
    INTO @Inserted (SrcContentID, TgtContentID)
SELECT Tag
    FROM Private.Content AS cglobal
    INNER JOIN @Missing AS m ON cglobal.ContentID = m.SrcContentID
```

What worked for me was a simple alias table, like this:

```
INSERT INTO con1 
    (Tag) 
    OUTPUT **con2**.ContentID, INSERTED.ContentID 
    INTO @Inserted (SrcContentID, TgtContentID)
SELECT Tag
    FROM Private.Content con1
    **INNER JOIN Private.Content con2 ON con1.id=con2.id**
    INNER JOIN @Missing AS m ON con1.ContentID = m.SrcContentID
```